# Simplify calculation for matrix elements in quantum electrodynamics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, s-matrix-theory, matrix-elements

So I am learning quantum field theory. At the moment I have a look at the interactions between electrons/positrons and photons, which is quantum electrodynamics. I want to calculate matrix elements of the form
\begin{align}
<\gamma(p_1)|S^{(1)}|e^-(p_2)e^+(p_3)>
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
S^{(1)} = ie\int d^4x:\bar{\Psi}\gamma_\mu A^\mu\Psi:
\end{align}
My problem here is, that if you do this calculation by hand, this is an absolute mess. Since this is a homework problem, I assume that there is a trick that simplifys this calculation. I know Wick's theorem, but I think this can't be used here since the S-Matrix is not time ordered. Does anyone know where I can find some examples of this kind of matrix elements in the literature, so I can figure out an better way to compute this?

Comment: Why do you say that this calculation is a mess?

Comment: because the $\Psi$ and $A^\mu$ contain sums of  creation/annihilation operators and therefore I got 8 terms each acting on the $<|>$ states

Comment: Yes, but from the mode expansion of $A^{\mu}$ only the term destroying a photon of momentum $p_1$ from the final state will survive. The same logic applies to the two spinor fields. So, this consideration reduces your calculations considerably.

Comment: The reaction $e^+e^-\to\gamma$ is kinematically forbidden (the rest mass is at least $2m_e$ before and goes to $0$ after). Don’t you mean $e^+e^-\to\gamma\gamma$ ? (two photons)

Comment: *an better way* [Feynman diagrams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram)